# Need to set checkboxes as checked based on string from model data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I am trying to set the checked property based on a comma delimited string stored in the model. This issue is the checked property is not being. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here is what I have:

Data returned from controller...

```
V1P01,V1P02,V1P03
```

View code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var array = "@Model.IncidentVehicle.VA_Sub1VehicleDamage".split(',');
    for (var i in array)
        $("[name=myCheckboxName][value=" + $.trim(array[i]) + "]").attr('checked', true);
    });
```

```html
<div class="carCBsPassenger">
    <input name="V1P01" id="V1P01" type="checkbox" value="V1P01" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P02" id="V1P02" type="checkbox" value="V1P02" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P03" id="V1P03" type="checkbox" value="V1P03" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P04" id="V1P04" type="checkbox" value="V1P04" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P05" id="V1P05" type="checkbox" value="V1P05" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P06" id="V1P06" type="checkbox" value="V1P06" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P07" id="V1P07" type="checkbox" value="V1P07" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P08" id="V1P08" type="checkbox" value="V1P08" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P09" id="V1P09" type="checkbox" value="V1P09" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P10" id="V1P10" type="checkbox" value="V1P10" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P11" id="V1P11" type="checkbox" value="V1P11" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P12" id="V1P12" type="checkbox" value="V1P12" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P13" id="V1P13" type="checkbox" value="V1P13" style="border: none;" />
    <input name="V1P14" id="V1P14" type="checkbox" value="V1P14" style="border: none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try using prop() instead of attr ex  $("[name=myCheckboxName][value=" + $.trim(array[i]) + "]").prop('checked', true);

Comment: None of those checkboxes have the `name` attribute in your selector?

Comment: I figured it out just after posting it. But you are correct Rory. I needed to have the name not the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the checkboxes have a `name` attribute of `myCheckboxName`. Also, you are missing some opening braces, and have a closing bracket at the end causing syntax errors. Try this:

```
var array = "V1P01,V1P02,V1P03".split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $("#" + $.trim(array[i])).attr('checked', true);
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cSF55/)

---

Also, assuming that the format of the list from the server does not change, you can remove the loop by replacing the string to select the elements by their `id`:

```
var selector = '#' + array.replace(/\,/g, ',#');
$(selector).attr('checked', true);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4V5mV/1/)

Comment: You should consider using `.prop()` as opposed to `.attr()` for checking the boxes...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .prop() method instead. Also I switched the for loop for a jQuery .each().

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6PeDS/)

```
var array = ['V1P01', 'V1P02', 'V1P03'];
$.each(array, function(key, val){
    $('input[value="' + $.trim(array[key]) + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should change selector and use prop() method. And maybe use single quotes in value.

```
$(".carCBsPassenger input[value='" + $.trim(array[i]) + "']").prop('checked', true);
```